# Expo build android throw an erro "Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'."

Tags: android, react-native, expo

```bash
> Task :expo-font:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :expo-image:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :expo-image-loader:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :expo-image-picker:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :expo-keep-awake:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :expo-media-library:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :expo-secure-store:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :expo-splash-screen:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :expo-application:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-clipboard:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-constants:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-error-recovery:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-file-system:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-font:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-image:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-image-loader:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-image-picker:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-keep-awake:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-media-library:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-secure-store:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :lottie-react-native:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :lottie-react-native:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :expo-modules-core:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :lottie-react-native:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-clipboard:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-application:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-constants:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-error-recovery:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-font:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

warning: the transform cache was reset.

                Welcome to Metro v0.72.4

              Fast - Scalable - Integrated

> Task :expo-file-system:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-image:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-image-loader:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-keep-awake:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-media-library:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-secure-store:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-image-picker:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :expo-splash-screen:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :expo:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-clipboard_clipboard:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-clipboard_clipboard:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-community_datetimepicker:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :react-native-clipboard_clipboard:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-community_datetimepicker:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-pager-view:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-pager-view:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-pager-view:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-screens:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-svg:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-screens:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :react-native-svg:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :react-native-svg:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-vector-icons:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-vector-icons:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :react-native-vector-icons:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-webview:compileReleaseLibraryResources

> Task :react-native-webview:parseReleaseLocalResources

> Task :react-native-screens:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :react-native-webview:generateReleaseRFile

> Task :expo:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-application:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-modules-core:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-application:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-clipboard:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-clipboard:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-constants:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-constants:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-error-recovery:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-error-recovery:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-file-system:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-file-system:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-font:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-font:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-image:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-image:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-image-loader:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-image-loader:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-image-picker:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-image-picker:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-keep-awake:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-keep-awake:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-media-library:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-media-library:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-secure-store:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-secure-store:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo-splash-screen:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :expo-splash-screen:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :expo:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :lottie-react-native:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :lottie-react-native:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :lottie-react-native:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

[stderr] 
Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

[stderr] 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

[stderr] 
Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

[stderr] 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :expo-modules-core:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :lottie-react-native:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseBuildConfig

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

Error: /home/expo/workingdir/build/App.tsx: Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins

    at LazyResult.getAsyncError (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/nativewind/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:182:11)

    at LazyResult.sync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/nativewind/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:401:20)

    at LazyResult.stringify (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/nativewind/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:369:10)

    at LazyResult.get css [as css] (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/nativewind/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:174:17)

    at extractStyles (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/nativewind/dist/postcss/extract-styles.js:32:54)

    at PluginPass.enter (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/nativewind/dist/babel/index.js:100:67)

    at newFn (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:159:14)

    at NodePath._call (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:46:20)

    at NodePath.call (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:36:17)

    at NodePath.visit (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:82:31)

    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:86:16)

    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:65:19)

    at TraversalContext.visit (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:109:19)

    at traverseNode (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:18:17)

    at traverse (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:49:34)

    at transformFile (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:81:29)

    at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)

    at run (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:24:12)

    at run.next (<anonymous>)

    at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform-ast.js:23:41

    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

    at evaluateSync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)

    at sync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)

    at stopHiding - secret - don't use this - v1 (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/errors/rewrite-stack-trace.js:47:12)

    at transformFromAstSync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform-ast.js:44:83)

    at Object.transform (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/src/index.js:199:20)

    at Object.module.exports.transform (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-svg-transformer/index.js:39:30)

    at transformJSWithBabel (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:399:45)

    at Object.transform (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:572:18)

    at transformFile (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.flow.js:82:36)

    at Object.transform (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.flow.js:55:10)

    at execFunction (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:137:17)

    at execHelper (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:116:5)

    at execMethod (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:120:5)

    at process.messageListener (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:38:7)

    at process.emit (node:events:513:28)

    at emit (node:internal/child_process:946:14)

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

[stderr] 
error App.tsx: /home/expo/workingdir/build/App.tsx: Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins.

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

[stderr] 
Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

[stderr] 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

[stderr] 
Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/javaPackage/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

[stderr] 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseKotlin

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/core/utilities/EmulatorUtilities.kt: (30, 13): 'SERIAL: String!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/activityresult/ActivityResultsManager.kt: (52, 24): Parameter 'activity' is never used

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/events/KModuleEventEmitterWrapper.kt: (90, 7): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/jni/JavaScriptObject.kt: (59, 33): Parameter 'null' is never used

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/jni/JavaScriptObject.kt: (100, 5): Parameter 'null' is never used

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/modules/Module.kt: (43, 7): 'coroutineScope: CoroutineScope' is deprecated. Use a scope from the AppContext

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/Either.kt: (24, 11): Parameter 'type' is never used

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/Either.kt: (27, 11): Parameter 'type' is never used

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/Either.kt: (44, 11): Parameter 'type' is never used

w: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/kotlin/types/Either.kt: (59, 11): Parameter 'type' is never used

[stderr] 
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

[stderr] 
1: Task failed with an exception.

[stderr] 
-----------

[stderr] 
* What went wrong:

[stderr] 
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

[stderr] 
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

[stderr] 
* Try:

[stderr] 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr] 
> Run with --scan

[stderr] 
to get full insights.

[stderr] 
==============================================================================

[stderr] 
2: Task failed with an exception.

[stderr] 
-----------

[stderr] 
* What went wrong:

[stderr] 
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

[stderr] 
* Try:

[stderr] 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr] 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr] 
==============================================================================

[stderr] 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[stderr] 
BUILD FAILED in 3m 52s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.

Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

328 actionable tasks: 328 executed

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "com.hfuthole.app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "npx cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider expo start --web",
    "build:android": "eas build -p android --profile production",
    "update": "eas update --channel production --message \"update\""
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^11.3.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.2",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.5",
    "@gorhom/portal": "^1.0.14",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.11",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll": "^5.3.1",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.5",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.12",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "ahooks": "^3.7.4",
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "expo-asset": "~8.7.0",
    "expo-clipboard": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-image": "^1.2.3",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.0.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.0.0",
    "hox": "^2.1.0",
    "immer": "^9.0.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "qaq-font": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.1",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^15.0.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.1.2",
    "react-native-paper-dropdown": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-popover-view": "^5.1.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.9",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.1",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-persist-expo-securestore": "^2.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "use-immer": "^0.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.71.2",
    "@types/react-native-tags": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.51.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.51.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "prettier": "^2.8.2",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.6",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

eas.json

```json
{
  "build": {
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "image": "latest"
      },
      "channel": "production"
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      },
      "channel": "preview2"
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "channel": "preview3"
    }
  }
}
```

app.json

```bash
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "工大树洞",
    "slug": "hfuthole",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/splash.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/bg.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.hfuthole.app"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/splash.png"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ],
      "package": "com.hfuthole.app"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/splash.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxxxx"
      }
    },
    "owner": "snowingfox"
  }
}
```

my repo: https://github.com/HFUTHole/HFUTHoleApp

may be it caused by nativewind because of error
`Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins`
`at LazyResult.getAsyncError (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/nativewind/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:182:11)`

and

react-async-storage

```bash
[stderr] 
error App.tsx: /home/expo/workingdir/build/App.tsx: Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins.

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
```

I'm using lottie, nativewind and some may caused error packages, but idk what happened, could some one help me?

Comment: I have the exact same error, did you make any progress with this?

Comment: @Joeboulton i solved it by using yarn instead of pnpm or npm, pnpm may cause peerDenpedcies or some strange issues, so